# Why can't I reassign variables in this function?

Tags: python, list, integer, mutability

Here is the question:

> You will be given an array of numbers. You have to sort the odd numbers in ascending order while leaving the even numbers at their original positions.

Here is my code:

```
def sort_array(source_array):
    odd_ints = []

    for i in source_array:
        if i % 2 == 1:
            odd_ints.append(i)
            odd_ints.sort()
        else:
            pass
    counter = 0
    for x in source_array:
        if x % 2 == 1:
            x = odd_ints[counter]
            counter += 1
            print(source_array)
        else:
            pass

    return source_array
```

When I test it, it does this:

```
>>> sort_array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4])
[5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]
[5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]
[5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]

[5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]
```

For some reason, I can't re-assign the variable `x` in the function to `odd_ints` in ascending order. Would anyone know the problem in my code?

Comment: `x = odd_ints[counter]` has absolutely no impact on `source_array`, you're just reassigning the loop variable.

Comment: You can reassign it. It just gets overwritten again on the next iteration of for loop with whatever comes next in source_array.

Comment: Pls fix your indentation. This code is invalid.

Comment: @dawg that just puts the odd numbers at the end and even first: `[8, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to save the positions of the odd integers as well to replace them:

```
def sort_array(source_array):
    odd_ints = []
    positions = []
    counter = 0 #need counter to get positions
    for i in source_array:
        if i % 2 == 1:
            odd_ints.append(i) #keep the values
            positions.append(counter) #keep the position
        counter += 1
    odd_ints.sort() #sort for replacement
    counter2 = 0 #need second counter to place sorted list
    for pos in positions:
        source_array[pos] = odd_ints[counter2] #place the sorted values
        counter2 += 1
    return source_array

print(sort_array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified answer by @eli-harold to use slightly more readable syntax:

```py
def sort_array(source_array):
    odd_ints = []
    positions = []
    for i, elem in enumerate(source_array):
        if elem % 2:
            odd_ints.append(elem)  # keep the values
            positions.append(i)  # keep the position

    odd_ints.sort()  # sort for replacement

    for pos, elem in zip(positions, odd_ints):
        source_array[pos] = elem  # place the sorted values
    return source_array

print(sort_array([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4]))
```

Or, being more concise,

```py
def sort_array(source_array):
    positions, odd_ints = zip(*[(i, elem)
                                for i, elem in enumerate(source_array)
                                if elem % 2])
    pos = iter(positions)
    for elem in sorted(odd_ints):
        source_array[next(pos)] = elem
    return source_array
```

Bonus: if we should not sort inplace (modify given list), the following will work:

```py
def sort_array(arr):
    odd_sorted_it = iter(sorted(el for el in arr if el % 2))
    return [el if not el % 2 else next(odd_sorted_it) for el in arr]
```

Comment: Your second `sort_array` should be the answer. +1 from me. Super simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Separate the odds with indexes into a dict;
2. Sort the odds and reset the indexes into odd slots;
3. Insert those odds into the original list.

Example:

```
def sort_the_odds(li):
    odds={idx:n for idx,n in enumerate(li) if n%2}

    for idx,val in zip([t[0] for t in sorted(odds.items())],
            [t[1] for t in sorted(odds.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])]):
        li[idx]=val
    
    return li

>>> sort_the_odds([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
[10, 1, 8, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2, 9]

>>> sort_the_odds([5, 3, 2, 8, 1, 4])
[1, 3, 2, 8, 5, 4]
```